# SQL query (Oracle DB) from R - keyword error

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I'm trying to run some SQL queries from R. Database is Oracle.

Simple query like this works

```
  query<-"SELECT tab1.negotiationid FROM espdds.esp_fnegotiations tab1 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY"
```

when I try to rename the column selected like this

```
  query<-"SELECT tab1.negotiationid as 'col1' FROM espdds.esp_fnegotiations tab1 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY"
```

or

```
  query<-"SELECT tab1.negotiationid 'col1' FROM espdds.esp_fnegotiations tab1 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY"
```

it returns me an error "FROM keyword not found where expected".

Any thought? Thanks

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Skip them here.

Comment: ooh ok I didn't know. Thanks

Comment: Put the comment as an answer so I can mark the question as Closed and solved. Thanks